# Why are these URIs getting chopped to just "i"?

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink

Alright, so I have a link using my custom syntax.  This is part of my parser (sans the XSS scrubber part), and it's the problematic one that I've isolated one of the remaining bugs in.  For some reason, the URI `http://ur.i` is getting truncated to merely `"i"`.

Anyone who knows why gets a pony.

```
var str = "[inner -&gt; http://ur.i]";

str = str.replace(/\[([^\]]+?)\s*(\||-&gt;)\s*((?!-&gt;)[^\]])+]/g, function(m, iH, separator, hr){
  console.log('hr: '); console.log(hr);
  return '<a class="'+ (separator.match(/-&gt;/) ? 'adlns-btn' : 'adlns-link') +'" href="'+ hr +'">' +
            iH +
         '</a>';
});

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` quantifier should be *inside* the parentheses, not *outside*:

```
/\[([^\]]+?)\s*(\||-&gt;)\s*((?!-&gt;)[^\]]+)]/g
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You lack to match the whitespace after `-&gt;` , try the following:

```
/\[([^\]]+?)\s*(\||-&gt;)\s*((?!-&gt;\s)[^\]])+]/g
```

Comment: Nope. See my answer for the real issue.